# File.WriteAllText is changing the start of my files according to Git

Tags: c#, git

I have a very simple C# program which iterates over a number of files and replaces a string in all the files.

However, when I compare these files using Git, it highlights a change to all my files.

My C# code is:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string file in files)
{
    string fileText = File.ReadAllText(fileName, Encoding.UTF8);
    string newText = fileText.Replace("hello", "goodbye");
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, newText, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Which as far as I'm concerned, looks good.
However, when I run this program and execute `git status` on the repository, I see differences in every file.

Using a program like Github Desktop or SourceTree reveals the following changes:

**Github Desktop**

[image: Github Desktop Screenshot]

**Sourcetree**

[image: Sourcetree Screenshot]

Thank you for any tips or ideas anyone may have. They're greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: I suspect its writing a byte-order-mark.  Just a guess: the encoding you're using when writing the file is different from the existing files encoding.  Is the original file UTF-8?

Comment: By the way, you are writing the `original` text back to the file, `not` the transformed text.  So @Amy might have something there

Comment: @Amy I think you're right! Adding a method to get the encoding for a file and using that seems to have fixed my issue. Thanks.
MickyD that was just a typo in the question, but thanks for spotting it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SaveFileDialog producing unrecognized character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397355/savefiledialog-producing-unrecognized-character)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This character is the [Unicode Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) preamble, which is automatically added by the `WriteAllText` method.

If you want to write files without BOM, you have to create custom encoding:

```
Encoding utf8NoBom = new UTF8Encoding(false);
```

And you then pass the instance as third parameter of the `WriteAllLines` method:

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, fileText, utf8NoBom);
```

Comment: Please note that for (at least) [mscorlib .Net 4.7.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_File_WriteAllText_System_String_System_String_) the default Encoding is UTF-8 without BOM (see remarks). If you stroll through the *Reference Source* you will notice that MS changed the default encoding to UTF-8 without BOM for other stuff as well (i.e `StreamWriter`).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the comment from @Amy I have managed to identify the issue.
I assumed all my files were encoded as UTF-8, but this wasn't the case.

Using the answer specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19283954/5577534) I was able to identify the encoding of my file and using that when reading/writing from/to the file.

My code now looks like this (using the 'GetEncoding' method specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19283954/5577534)):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string file in files)
{
    Encoding fileEncoding = GetEncoding(fileName);
    string fileText = File.ReadAllText(fileName, fileEncoding);
    string newText = fileText.Replace("hello", "goodbye");
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, newText, fileEncoding);
}
```